# How can I read a file in a closed excel file using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am new in VBA, and I have been doing a research on how to find certain words in a sheet. So far I can do it in the active worksheet but not in another workbook in a different folder. Can anybody help me to find the way to find a word in a closed excel file? This is what I use to find a word in the current active file from where I am running the macro. Thank you in advanced.

```
 Cells.Find(What:="24643", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
 xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
 , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cells`, unless it is qualified by a worksheet reference, will *always* refer to the `ActiveSheet.Cells`.

Likewise, `ActiveCell` *always* refers to the ActiveSheet's ActiveCell.

So to modify this for other workbooks, do qualify it like:

```
Dim foundRange as Range
With Workbooks("Book2.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")   '#Modify as needed
    Set foundRange = .Cells.Find(What:="24643", After:=.Cells(1,1), _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
End With
If Not foundRange Is Nothing Then foundRange.Activate
```

You may need to change `.Cells(1,1)` to some other cell location depending on what you want to do.

I do not think it is possible to use the `.Find` method against a *closed* workbook file.

You can open the file, first:

```
Dim wbFind as Workbook
Set wbFind = Workbooks.Open("c:\path\to\your\file.xlsx")
```

And then use that with the method above like:

```
Dim foundRange as Range

With wbFind.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Modify as needed
    Set foundRange = .Cells.Find(What:="24643", After:=.Cells(1,1), _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
End With
If Not foundRange Is Nothing Then foundRange.Activate
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mr.David. I implemented and finds the column titles in a different file.